# How can I get my address via web3?

Tags: solidity, web3js

I'm using web3, truffle and testrpc.

In my smart contract, some of the functions can only be called by the owner (or creator) of the contract (i.e. onlyOwner functions). So, I've defined some modifier for that. Also, in the smart contract, I have defined a variable called owner that can be called by anyone to see who the owner is.

I'm designing a UI. I'd like to alert the users, in UI, if they call the onlyOwner functions (e.g. you're not the owner). In my .js file I can call owner.call(); to get the owner address. But I don't know how to get the users address to compare it with the owner address.

**Question**: How can I get the user's address via web3?

---

Also, when we switch the default account (i.e. the first account) in MetaMask to 2nd, 3rd, .. account, how the .js file can recognize it and use that account as the default one?

Answer (score 8):

If you are using web(version 0.19.0: latest stable), you can do

**1. Download Web3**

```
bower install web3@0.19.0
```

**2. Algo to load Web3, check the connection and retrieve the accounts**

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="address"></div>

    <script src="bower_components/web3/dist/web3.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        window.addEventListener('load', function() {


            // Load WEB3
            // Check wether it's already injected by something else (like Metamask or Parity Chrome plugin)
            if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined') {
                web3 = new Web3(web3.currentProvider);  

            // Or connect to a node
            } else {
                web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));
            }

            // Check the connection
            if(!web3.isConnected()) {
                console.error("Not connected");

            }

            var account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
            var accountInterval = setInterval(function() {
              if (web3.eth.accounts[0] !== account) {
                account = web3.eth.accounts[0];
                document.getElementById("address").innerHTML = account;
              }
            }, 100);

        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**3. Auto-reload after switching account**

The solution right now is a basic `setInterval` function

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer. But, don't you think we're setting the account as account[0]. Assume we switch to account[1] in MetaMask, then how web3 (in .js file) can detect it and set account=account[1]? Am I right that your answer explains: how we can set user's account to account[0], but it doesn't show how we can get the user's current address? (assume we manually set the account to account[1] in MetaMasK browser extension.). Thanks

Comment: I don't know if you have seen the update. But the array always contains one element which the current metamask address.

Comment: To pull a change. A setInterval function does the job

Comment: I am using a newer version of web 3 and `web3.eth.accounts[0]` is giving me `undefined` instead of the address of the account

Comment: The `web3.eth.getAccounts()` is giving the addresses of all the accounts

Comment: @ZeeshanAhmadKhalil `web3.eth.getAccounts()` now gives me "Method not found" error...

Comment: @Jim I was using `web3^1.0.0-beta.55`. The current version is `web3^1.5.2`. Check your web 3.0 version in `package.json`, see their [documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.4.0/index.html) and find the function against your own version to get all the accounts.

Answer (score 8):

var account = web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress

*for web3 1.2.0

Answer (score 2):

If the user is using MetaMask:
MetaMask has said that it will deprecate injecting web3 into the global object. However they have replaced this with an `ethereum` object which is equivalent to `web3.currentProvider`.

Since 2018, it has become necessary to request permission to get the current user's account address, which can be done by making a call to `ethereum.enable()`. The call to enable will return a promise that will resolve to an array of addresses containing the current address, and will also populate the `selectedAddress` property of the `ethereum` object:

```js
let _web3:Web3;
const ethereum = (window as any).ethereum;
if (ethereum) {
    if (!ethereum.selectedAddress) {
        await ethereum.enable(); // <<< ask for permission
    }
    userAccount = ethereum.selectedAddress;
    _web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
}   
else {
   ...< connect to local rpc >
}
return _web3;
```

When the user changes accounts on MetaMask, that should ripple through the currentProvider which, i believe, causes a page refresh.

Answer (score 2):

`web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress` is deprecated

MetaMask no longer injects web3 so `web3.eth.accounts[0]` and so on won't work.

See https://docs.metamask.io/guide/provider-migration.html#replacing-window-web3

You should migrate to `window.ethereum` and use it for all operations.

But `window.ethereum.selectedAddress` is deprecated too.

**Correct way is `await window.ethereum.request({ method: 'eth_accounts' })`**

See https://docs.metamask.io/guide/ethereum-provider.html#legacy-properties

But if you are using web3.js directly, like from nodejs, then you can do this:

```js
const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
console.log(accounts[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
var acc = web3.currentProvider.selectedAddress;
```